Do provinces have the right to require more than the list of obligatory documents and papers required for "empadronamiento" specified in Ley 7/1985?
Last month I applied for empadronamiento in one of the cities of the Tarragona province of Catalunya. I live there in a room that I payed for via AirBnb. I gave the AirBnB receipts for two months to the clerk in the town hall, the recepts were said by the clerk to be not enough and I was asked for the rental contract. As I do not hold such contract, empadronamiento was refused to me. I 2023 in Sabadell, I succeeded getting my empadronamiento based on a receipt from AirBnB for just one month. The clerk from Sabadell understood my precarious situation, and decided to send an inspector to the place when I then resided, and shortly after the said inspector's visit I was granted empadronamiento. I have told this story to the clerk from Tarragona, asking her to utilize such an inspector as the ultimate proof of my residence in Tarragona. She refused saying that she cannot grant me empadronamiento without a rental contract, and that a receipt from AirBnB is not enough, and assuming perhaps that a stranger as myself is unlikely to pursue enough knowledge on the relevant laws and decrees, she added that the rules of getting empadronamiento are different in each province. I did some research and have not found anything in Ley 7/1985 that supports her claim:
Artículo 15.
Toda persona que viva en España está obligada a inscribirse en el Padrón del municipio en el que resida 
habitualmente. Quien viva en varios municipios deberá inscribirse únicamente en el que habite durante 
más tiempo al año.
[...]
Artículo 16.
2. La inscripción en el Padrón municipal contendrá como obligatorios sólo los siguientes datos:

a) Nombre y apellidos.

b) Sexo.

c) Domicilio habitual, con especificación de la referencia catastral, en el territorio fiscal 
común o el código equivalente en los territorios forales, siempre que el domicilio cuente con referencia 
catastral o código equivalente.

d) Nacionalidad.

e) Lugar y fecha de nacimiento.

f) Número de documento nacional de identidad o, tratándose de extranjeros:

1.º Número de identidad de extranjero que conste en el certificado de inscripción en el Registro Central 
de Extranjeros expedido por las autoridades españolas, o en su defecto, número del documento acreditativo 
de la identidad o del pasaporte en [...]

2.º Número de identidad de extranjero que conste en documento, en vigor, [...]

g) Certificado o título escolar o académico que se posea.

h) Cuantos otros datos puedan ser necesarios para la elaboración del Censo Electoral, 
siempre que se garantice el respeto a los derechos fundamentales reconocidos en la Constitución Española.


1. Do provinces have the right to extend the list of obligatory documents and papers required for "empadronamiento"? If so, what is the legal basis for that?
2. Is there any decree or regulation that specifies a rental contract as one of the requirements for empadronamiento?

that law's art. 16 only says what is recorded in the register, not what you need to get your data registred. Maybe you should read the guidance page of the Spanish Administration on gaining residency

You have to provide sufficient evidence of your domicilio habitual, your 'habitual residence'. Either (a) property deeds or (b) tenancy agreement for 12+ months and utility bill, or if you have no contract then (c) a letter to that effect from the property owner, a copy of their ID and the official might require the owner's presence. Receipts for two months are unlikely to be seen as sufficient evidence of habitual residence.

@Lag In what legislation is such sufficient evidence of domicilio habitual specified? I Sabadell I was told that if I stay somewhere just one month it is not enough. That's why they send an inspector that came after this period. It is also the reason why I paid for two months upfront in Tarragona - thinking I will get empadronamiento with a receipt.

It's not specified, it's up to the municipality. Try https://www.citizensadvice.org.es/padron-municipal-de-habitantes-municipal-census-of-habitants/

I shouldn't have been so definitive about the period of the tenancy agreement but the broader point remains: evidence of domicilio habitual sufficient to persuade the official.

@Lag From citizenadvice.org.es: The town hall has the power to accept other documents, making the necessary checks [...] It is very helpful to learn that, but I would like to know which legislation devolves such power to the municipality. I want to be sure that the rule of law is followed and not just a custom.
